# How to know how many keys did map-reduce job processed?

Tags: mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

How can map-reduce job generate metrics about how many keys it has processed and give data like the following?

% of keys that belonged to this particular value.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom counter in reduce method and increment it every-time the reduce method is called.  Please note that the reduce method is called only once for a given key.  Once the job is completed successfully, this custom counter will appear in the log.

Comment: there is already the reduce_input_groups counter which does exactly that, but this is not I think what the OP asks, even if the question is not very clear